# Get logitech audio device sink name

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, logitech

I am using the logitech mic for recording the audio.

I am able to find the device name using the following command:

```
pactl list short sources | grep "alsa_input.usb" | awk '{ print $2 }'
```

op: `alsa_input.usb-046d_0823_D81A0330-00-U0x46d0x823_1.analog-stereo`

So now I want the sink name of that logitech mic.
 I tried using the following command:

```
pactl list short sinks
```

But it gives the system default sink instead of logitech mic sink.

Also I wanted the index number of loaded logitech pulseaudio module?

Is there any command  to get index number of loaded pulseaudio module.

Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 1):

- Input has Sources only, the only way to get sink for input (mic) is to use loopback  module.

  1. Create a virtual sink

     ```
     pactl load-module module-null-sink sink_name=Virtual1 sink_properties=device.description=Virtual1
     ```
  2. Loopback the microphone to it

     ```
     pactl load-module module-loopback sink=Virtual1 source=alsa_input.usb-046d_0823_D81A0330-00-U0x46d0x823_1.analog-stereo
     ```
- Not sure if you  mean source index: (by changing `awk` to get 1st column instead)

  ```
  pactl list short sources | grep "alsa_input.usb" | awk '{ print $1 }'
  ```

  Otherwise, if you mean a module use similar command

  ```
  pactl list short modules | grep "portion-of-module-name" | awk '{ print $1 }'
  ```

  Change `portion-of-module-name`, try `pactl list short modules` to see full list